# font-lock no colors after adding a new keyword

Tags: emacs, elisp, font-lock

I'm trying to provide better highlighting for C/C++ projects based on ctags file. So I created this:

```
  (defun process-file (file)
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert-file-contents file)
  (split-string (buffer-string) "\n" t)))



(defun ctags-highlight()
    (interactive)
    (setq linelist (nthcdr 6 (process-file "/home/willian/Documents/M1-Class/OS/nachos/code/tags")))

    (while linelist
      (setq temp (split-string (car linelist) "\t"))
      (setq keyword (car temp))
      (setq type (car (cdddr temp)))
      (cond
       ((string= type "v")
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-variable-name-face)))
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-variable-name-face))))
       ((string= type "f")
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-function-name-face)))
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-function-name-face))))
       ((string= type "d")
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-constant-name-face)))
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-constant-name-face))))
       ((string= type "e")
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-constant-name-face)))
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-constant-name-face))))
       ((string= type "c")
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-type-name-face)))
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-type-name-face))))
       ((string= type "t")
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-type-name-face)))
        (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
                                '((,keyword 1 font-lock-type-name-face))))
       )
      (setq linelist (cdr linelist))))
```

But after I execute this code, I get no highlighting at all.

Does anybody know where the mistake is in code above?

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot use a let-bound variable in a list without using the back-tick instead of the single quote at the beginning of the list.  So try changing all of the lists so that a back-tick precedes it instead of a single quote.  That being said, I haven't tested the code in the question or verified anything else as to its functionality.  The single quote in front of a list means take everything literally and don't evaluate anything in the list, whereas a back-tick means evaluate stuff inside the list that begins with a comma.

Comment: Also, using `setq` on something without first making it let-bound has the effect of creating a `global` variable unless the variable is already defined as buffer-local or global.  Whereas, it is possible to make a variable temporary for the duration of the function by first defining it as let-bound -- e.g., `(let (temp keyword type) . . . (setq temp "hello-world") . . .)`

Comment: You can use https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio to inspect the result of adding your keywords, and to single step every part of the font-lock machinery. Hopefully, you will be able to spot your error this way.